# Noob having difficulties with Haskell - Not in scope errors

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner with Haskell and having some difficulties getting a tuple consisting of 4 empty lists to work. The below code is the entirety of my Haskell Program.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

l = []
h = []
a = []
x = []

TextEditor = (l, h, a, x) 

backspace :: TextEditor -> TextEditor
backspace (TextEditor l h a x) = 
    (TextEditor(reverse (tail (reverse l))) [] a x)
```

I get multiple errors.

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘TextEditor’
Not in scope: type constructor 'TextEditor'
```

Despite googling I can't work out what's wrong with my functions. Could someone help push me in the right direction please?

Comment: Is `TextEditor` supposed to be type, or some sort of value? In your code you're mixing both together, you can't do that.

Comment: `reverse (tail (reverse l))` is already defined as `init` in the module `Data.List`.

Comment: @chepner I'm learning Haskell as part of an assignment. Annoyingly we are only allowed to use the head, tail, concatenate and the dot operator. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done here is declared a top-level scoped *symbol* (like a variable) called `TextEditor`.

What you probably want to do is to declare a `TextEditor` data type and its corresponding type constructor, which might be done like this:

```
data TextEditor = TextEditor ([String], [String], [String], [String])
```

(Your definition may vary; you didn't declare the types of `l`, `h`, `a` or `x` so I'm just assuming `[String]`)

I'd recommend reading up about `data` declarations and typeclass definitions in [the appropriate LYAH chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

Comment: The definitions of `l`, `h`, `a`, and `x` appear to be irrelevant, other than as part of the incorrect attempt to define `TextEditor` as a type of tuple containing four lists.

Comment: Correct; that's what I was trying to convey in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're trying to do is this:

```
type L = [Char]  -- aka String
type H = [Char]
type A = [Char]
type X = [Char]

data TextEditor = TextEditor L H A X -- You really should use more discriptive names

backspace :: TextEditor -> TextEditor
backspace (TextEditor l h a x) = 
    (TextEditor(reverse (tail (reverse l))) [] a x)
```